# could I only use the correlation value of two variables to say that one variable has negative or positive effect on another variable?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, correlation

Fro example, for variable A and B, I have their time series respectively for 1000 long.Then using those to calculate their correlation is 0.8. Could I say that increase of A would also increase B. A has impacts on B .(I know the A is input variable, B is dependent  variable) .

Comment: [Correlation does not imply causation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation).

Comment: What if I change A, then I got the time series of B. Could they have causation this time ? thanks so much!!!

Comment: Without knowing more details about A and B it is impossible to say anything meaningful about them.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! what should I do now ??

Comment: That depends, but I would want to gather a lot more evidence to understand what is going on. No easy answers here.